# How to Deploy WSO2 API Manager (wso2am) in docker to the remote server?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I could run it in the localhost but deployment to the remote server needs tweaking deployment.toml file. Where do we need to make those changes in order to properly deploy it?

Comment: Have you tried https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/deployment-best-practices/changing-the-hostname/#changing-the-api-m-hostname ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a docker compose file as in [1]. In the compose file you can mount the config directory and the configs in the deployment toml is applied there[2].

If you want to use just docker, then you can again mount only the deployment.toml file via docker volume mount [3].

1. https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim/tree/master/docker-compose/apim-with-analytics
2. https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim/blob/master/docker-compose/apim-with-analytics/docker-compose.yml#L48
3. https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#start-a-container-with-a-volume